# duplicate symbol _RCTRemoteNotificationReceived

Tags: duplicates

I am not able to resolve this issue from so long please do help me anyone..

**Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error**

```
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)   

Ld /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify- bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/newNotify.app/newNotify normal arm64
cd /Users/anubhavpilania/newNotify/ios
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.4
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.4.sdk -
L/Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef
/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Intermediates.noindex/newNotify.build/Debug-iphoneos/newNotify.build/Objects-normal/arm64/newNotify.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=11.4 -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Intermediates.noindex/newNotify.build/Debug-iphoneos/newNotify.build/Objects-normal/arm64/newNotify_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -lc++ -ObjC /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTPushNotification.a /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTBlob.a /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTAzureNotificationHubManager.a /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libWindowsAzureMessaging.a /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTAnimation.a /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libReact.a /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTActionSheet.a /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTGeolocation.a /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTImage.a /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTLinking.a /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTNetwork.a /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTSettings.a /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTText.a /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTVibration.a /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTWebSocket.a -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Intermediates.noindex/newNotify.build/Debug-iphoneos/newNotify.build/Objects-normal/arm64/newNotify_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/newNotify.app/newNotify

 duplicate symbol _RCTRemoteNotificationReceived in:
/Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTPushNotification.a(RCTPushNotificationManager.o)
/Users/anubhavpilania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newNotify-bcawjuyeqhqkypfnultgtirfnbef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRCTAzureNotificationHubManager.a(RCTAzureNotificationHubManager.o)

ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Are you able to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: I resolved this error :).

Answer (score 8):

In my case this issue occurred when I switched from `PushNotificationIOS` provided with the React Native core to the extracted version from `@react-native-community/push-notification-ios`. (Around version RN 0.60)

After linking the new library and installing the CocoaPods dependencies of the iOS project this issue started popping up.

For some reason while setting up the core RN Push Notification library I manually added `libRCTPushNotification.a` to the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" of my project. Removing this reference to the core library resolved the issue and let me compile again.

Answer (score 5):

The PushNotificationIOS was split out from the core React Native. So this issue comes up when migrating to the new module @react-native-community/push-notification-ios.

To fix this, just remove or comment out the PushNotificationIOS library from the Podfile: ./ios/Podfile
    `pod 'React-RCTPushNotification', :path => '../node_modules/react- 
 native/Libraries/PushNotificationIOS'`

Then, run the following commands:
    `rm -rf Pods`
    `pod install`

Rebuild and then run your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Podfile you can also remove React-RCTPushNotification and add the following...

```
pod 'RNCPushNotificationIOS', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/push-notification-ios'
```

because React-RCTPushNotification is from 'react-native' but push notifications has been moved to @react-native-community.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue as @Padarom, upgrading.

In Podfile, I had to remove the RCTPushNotification line

```
 pod 'React',
    :path => "../node_modules/react-native",
    :inhibit_warnings => true,
    :subspecs => [
      "Core",
      "ART",
      "RCTActionSheet",
      "RCTAnimation",
      "RCTCameraRoll",
      .....
      "RCTPushNotification", <== REMOVE
```

after another pod install it worked